# Solve $28^x = 19^y+87^z$

Tags: number-theory

> Solve the equation $28^x = 19^y+87^z$, where $x,y,z$ are integers.

This is related to Beal's conjecture (and it turns out there are no integer solutions to the equation), but I am wondering how to first prove there are no integer solutions when $x,y,z$ are positive integers. For positive integers we can use the following argument:

Taking the equation modulo $19$ gives $28^x-(19^y+87^z) \equiv 9^x-11^z \equiv 0 \pmod{19}$. Thus, since the complete set of residues of $9^x$ modulo $19$ is $\{9,5,7,6,16,11,4,17,1\}$ and the complete set of residues of $11^z$ modulo $19$ is $\{11,7,1\}$. Therefore, $x = 3+9k_1$ and $y = 2+3k_2$, or $x = 6+9k_1$ and $y = 1+3k_2$, or $x = 9+9k_1$ and $y = 3+3k_2$ where $k_1, k_2 \in \mathbb{N}_0$.

How can we complete this argument and also extend it to all integers?

Comment: @lulu I am looking for a better solution.

Comment: http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c146h150669p849702

Answer (score 0):

The hard part of the problem has already been done, the argument proves it when $x,y,z$ are non-negative.

If $x$ is negative we have $\frac{1}{28^{-x}}=19^y+87^z$ and clearly the fraction on the right won't have $7$ as a factor of the denominator when we reduce it.

So $x$ cannot be negative.

Therefore $19^y+87^z$ must be an integer, this is clearly impossible if exactly one of $y$ and $z$ is negative. And if both are negative we have $\frac{1}{19^{-y}}+\frac{1}{87^{-z}}=\frac{87^{-y}+19^{-z}}{{87^{-y}19^{-z}}}$. Which is clearly not an integer, since the numerator is not a multiple of $19$.